Issues with MOD11A1 Dataset Download After 2022
I want to export the Daytime and Nighttime Land Surface Temperature from the MOD11A1 dataset and export it to Google Drive. I found that when I use the MYD11A1.061 (2002-2024) dataset, the Nighttime data I export is empty. On the other hand, when I use the MYD11A1.006 (2002-2022) dataset, I can correctly export the Nighttime data until 2022, but this dataset only includes data up to 2022, so I cannot get the data for 2023 and 2024. Could you please explain why this is happening?
The code is as follows, and the dataset code is at Line 55-59.
link
/**
 * Extract MODIS LST (daily) for each county in the US
 */


/**
 * Convert a collection to an image with each band representing an image
 * in previous collection
 */
var stackCollection = function(collection) {
  
  return ee.Image(collection.iterate(appendBand));
  
};

// Function to transform EVI collection to an image
function appendBand(current, previous){
  // create band name as sensor_DOY if the band has properties DOY and sensor
  // otherwise, band name as system:index
  var bandName = ee.Algorithms.If(ee.List(current.propertyNames()).contains('bandname'),
                                  current.get('bandname'),
                                  current.get('system:index'));
  // var bandName = current.get('system:index');
  // rename the band
  current = ee.Image(current).select([0],[bandName]);
  // Append it to the result (only return current item on first element)
  var accum = ee.Algorithms.If(ee.Algorithms.IsEqual(previous,null), current, ee.Image(previous).addBands(current));
  // return the accumulation
  return accum;
}


/**
 * Function to add "DOY" as bandname
 */ 
var addBandname = function(img) {
    var datestring = ee.String(img.get('system:index'));
    var format = 'YYYY_MM_dd';
    var eedate = ee.Date.parse(format, datestring);
    var doy = eedate.getRelative('day', 'year').add(1);
    var year = eedate.get('year');
    var bandname = ee.String(year).cat('_').cat(doy);
    return img.set('bandname',bandname);
};

/**
 * Function to import LST
 */ 
function stackLST(start,end,region,mask,mode) {
  // mode: 'Day' or 'Night'
  var band = 'LST_' + mode + '_1km';
  var qcband = 'QC_' + mode;
  var coll;
  if(start.substring(0,4) == '2001' | start.substring(0,4) == '2002') {
    coll = 'MODIS/006/MOD11A1';
  } else {
    // coll = 'MODIS/006/MYD11A1';
    coll = 'MODIS/061/MYD11A1';
  }
  var LST = ee.ImageCollection(coll)
              .filterDate(start,end)
              .filterBounds(region)
              .map(function(img) {return img.updateMask(img.select(qcband).eq(0))})
              .map(function(img) {return img.select(band).float().multiply(0.02).updateMask(mask)})
              .map(addBandname)
              .sort('DOY',true);
  
  var LSTstack = stackCollection(LST);

  return LSTstack;
}

/**
 * Export
 */
var exportTable = function(table, prefix) {
  Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: table.select([".*"], null, false),
    description: prefix,
    folder: 'Data_county',  //*********
    fileNamePrefix: prefix
  });
};


// get only counties with corn and soy
// var counties = UScounties16;
var counties = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2016/Counties');
Map.addLayer(counties, {}, 'ctn');

var start = '-03-01';  //*********
var end = '-11-30';   //*********

// loop through each year ***************
for(var i = 2021; i < 2024; i++) {

  var year = i.toString();
  // get crop mask
  var cropMask;
  if(i>2006)
  {
    var start_day = year + '-01-01'
    var end_day = year + '-12-31'
    
    var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NASS/CDL')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date(start_day, end_day))
                  .first();
    cropMask = dataset.select('cropland').eq(1); // 1- corn, 5 - soybean

    
  }
  else{
    
    var mcdband = 'MODIS/006/MCD12Q1/' + year + '_01_01';
    // var mcdband = 'MODIS/061/MCD12Q1/' + year + '_01_01';
    cropMask = ee.Image(mcdband).select('LC_Type1').clip(counties).eq(12);
  }
  
  // get LST day stack
  var LSTday_stack = stackLST(year+start, year+end, counties, cropMask, 'Day');

  var meanLSTday = LSTday_stack.reduceRegions(
    counties, ee.Reducer.mean(), 500);
  exportTable(meanLSTday, 'LSTday_daily_mean_' + year);
  
  // get LST night stack
  var LSTnight_stack = stackLST(year+start, year+end, counties, cropMask, 'Night');
  var meanLSTnight = LSTnight_stack.reduceRegions(
    counties, ee.Reducer.mean(), 500);
  
  exportTable(meanLSTnight, 'LSTnight_daily_mean_' + year);

}


